# What could be the reason for an accepted answer with 19 upvotes to be deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Today my (accepted) answer with **19 upvotes** got deleted, together with the related question. It was located at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164463/recommendations-to-get-started-with-drupal-and-grow/164475#164475 . This deletion happened without any notify or explanation. I discovered it via a rep decrease of **-205** ...

I have no more access to my own deleted answer. As opposed to other answers that get deleted sometimes by a moderator, which typically helps to understand why it got deleted. Should I still want (have) to do so, I can't even create a backup copy of the deleted answer anymore.

Some more details (stats) about this question (as it appeared on 25 Aug 2015 08:59:17 GMT.)

- it was from [herci](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/34116/herci), asked Jul 6 at 16:12.
- with title "Recommendations to get started with Drupal, and grow?".

The `upvoteCount` (= balance of upvotes and downvotes) was '**= 0**' as of Aug 25, so definitely not negative then ... Here is what I consider as the proof of that upvoteCount:

```
<div class="vote">
        <input type="hidden" name="_id_" value="164463">
        <a class="vote-up-off" title="This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear">up vote</a>
        <span itemprop="upvoteCount" class="vote-count-post ">0</span>
        <a class="vote-down-off" title="This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful">down vote</a>
        <a class="star-off" href="#" title="This is a favorite question (click again to undo)">favorite</a>
        <div class="favoritecount"><b>6</b></div>
</div>
```

However, here are the stats from [herci](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/34116/herci)'s profile page, added (on Aug 29, 2015) by [herci](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/34116/herci) as a comment to Molot's answers here:

- downvote 2015-08-27 10:04:25.
- removed 2015-08-27 20:26:02.

I know for sure this (so called) **deleted** question (and answer) is still visible to privileged users, because '**deleted**' on Drupal.SE actually means "*'**hidden**' for users with less then 10K rep*". At least that's what the [help pages](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) say:

> Once a post has been deleted, it will disappear for all users except developers, moderators, and users with over 10,000 reputation. Deleted answers are also visible to the original author. However, deleted posts can be undeleted by casting undelete votes. Once a post has 3 undelete votes, it will no longer be deleted.

**My questions**:

1. What is the **procedure** for "me" (I do NOT have +10K rep yet) to find out what happened, e.g. to understand why it got deleted? Note: this question is only about the procedure to find it out (not the actual reason, explanation, etc).
2. Why was this question not converted to a "wiki" answer instead?
3. Is there any procedure to "recover" a backup copy of the no longer available answer (different from using my own Drupal.SE backups)? Or is anybody with +10K rep willing to eMail me my answer in source format (cfr. my profile for contact details ...)?

**PS**: I don't worry about the -205, I trust some day I'll recover from that.

Comment: i wasn't involved in deleting that question/answer, but I _distinctly_ remember telling you to stop adding to it and adding to it, because it was already much too long for the Q+A format, and would end up having to be removed. You chose to ignore that request, you kept making it longer and longer, and broader and broader, and now it's been deleted. You can't possibly be surprised, it's exactly what you were told would happen

Comment: @Clive : merci (thank you) for your comment above. I respect you too much to really answer it, at least not in public. Except this: it does not answer any of my 3 bullets (questions near the end).

Comment: You've sort of answered 1. yourself (this is the procedure, and the mod involved has responded with the explanation). MPD has covered 2. implicitly (the question was deleted, so converting the answer to a wiki wouldn't make sense, and marking something as community wiki _encourages_ more activity, which doesn't work for an off-topic question). For 3., here's a pastebin of the answer's markdown in case you still don't have a copy: http://pastebin.com/4wj4SrtS

Comment: @clive : would you mind creating a similar pastebin please for the 2nd (important to me ...) deleted answer, located at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/166282/which-modules-would-you-recommend-for-creating-a-website-to-sell-tutorials-onlin/166283#166283 ? Similar "issue", similar recovery would solve it for me ...

Comment: Sure: http://pastebin.com/PTaUapVN

Answer (score 1):

Answers are always deleted when question is deleted. And closed questions with negative score can be deleted for various reasons. If they aren't deleted personally by moderators, they will be deleted automatically later, leaving you with possibly even bigger reputation loss.

Please note that well-received answer does not make question any more on topic, and it's question's own status and votes what count most. And this one is:

[image: Screenshot]

If you don't want this happen to you, simply don't answer bad questions.

As for investigation:

> Since June 2013, deleted questions and answers that were posted in the past 60 days, can be seen using the "deleted recent questions" and "deleted recent answers" links on the questions and answers tabs in your user profile.

If question still exists, you should see your own deleted answer with deletion date & description. If you can't see it, it probably means it was deleted along with question it was under - and unless it was your question or you are over 10k, you will see nothing. Alternatively it may mean it was older than 60 days and system decided not to care - but if question is not deleted and you do have a link, you will be able to see it.

Of course if moderator tells you that something will be deleted, listening to him (and asking if you have issues with what he says) is an ultimate way to know why it is happening.

Comment: Refer to the 'upvoteCount' part of my edited question. Want to re-edit your first paragraph? Thank you for the 60 days "hint" (you gave me a new idea ...). Rest assured that right now I cannot SEE my own deleted answer. That's part of what my question is about. FYI: nobody ever "told" me it "will be deleted". But it made me realize also a few things about how some things work on Drupal.SE .

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Question was on negative score, I don't know what you don't understand for my first paragraph and how to make it clearer for you.

Comment: question did NOT (repeat: did NOT) have a negative score ... Hang on until you'll see my comment to the other answer ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens You are mistaken or .... Question is at -1. If you don't believe, ask anyone over 10k - remember we can see it, even when it's deleted. And score is frozen at the very moment of deletion, so if it's at -1 now, it was at -1 when it was deleted. Next time make sure what you repeat is actually true.

Comment: I have posted "my" proof that the voting balance was 0 as of 25 Aug 2015 08:59:17 GMT ... And yes I'm willing to believe that "since then" there was another downvote. I bet very close around the time the delete happened (somewhere today). Full stop

Comment: Now is 27. So two days... if you consider that very close, your choice. But question did NOT have 0 score the day it was deleted. And automatic scripts that help with moderation triggers at least once a day (as far as I know, of course), so for purpose of moderation anything longer hardly can be seen as negligible. **Also, it's customary not to downvote questions that are on the way to be deleted**, because it serves no real purpose. But if you start answering them, and make people afraid these question will stay, **you are causing downvotes** on them.

Comment: @herci : 'you' (also with less then +10K) must be able to see in your own reputation history when exactly the last -2 came in for that "last" -1 downvote (of your question). Would you mind sharing with me here (via an extra comment) when exactly that last downvote came in? If you do, "I'll be in your debts forever" (hm, hm). And whatever YOU will say/confirm I will believe, unconditionally. But until further notice I will assume that happened AFTER Aug 25, 2015, 08:59:17 MGT ... because I trust my own backup proofs ... Even at the cost of the current -1 of "my" question here ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I am not sure what you will gain by reconstructing a vote timeline on that question.  It is very possible the last downvote was today, but it was at -1 when I deleted it.  If the post was brought to my attention with a total of 0, I may have still deleted it.  The question does not belong on DA.  If you feel like you are being singled out or treated unfairly by the moderators, then you can use the contact form at the bottom of the page to get in touch with the Community Manager team.

Comment: @MPD But I'm not a mod, and I'm not a 20k user he mentioned in other meta question. So there are at least 2 community members, not moderators, that disagree some of his actions. I mean, if moderators would be about to be punished (I don't believe you will, of course), remember you are not alone.

Comment: My point about that timeline is to proof that at the timestamp I mentioned the balance was 0. While Molot claims something else. IMHO only Herci will be able to tell me (if he wants to). About "my" feelings: don't worry about that. Last but not least: I don't think the "community manager team" is going to say or do anything that would be against the moderators they should be protecting / covering ... so why would I wast time on that? 1 more thing: I don't look for "punishments" or "guilties", only "solutions". And now I'm done (and considering DELETING my question ... because of the -1 ...)

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens CMs don't cover or protect diamond moderators.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, sorry for the late reply. This is from the profile page: downvote 2015-08-27 10:04:25Z. | removed  2015-08-27 20:26:02Z. // I'm sorry. Your answer was perfect and couldn't understand why it was deleted. Thanks for it. I have a full copy of it and will keep forever :)

Answer (score 1):

The question was deleted by me, and had a negative score on it.  It was closed on 2015/07/15, with votes from multiple people.

Those who can see deleted questions would see the comment I left:

> Deleting this. There is no real way this can be salvaged into a good question. It is really a shopping list question, blog.stackexchange.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping

This question was not a good fit for Drupal Answers, and having it around was encouraging activity on it.

See also https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: Refer to the 'upvoteCount' part of my edited question. I'm going to work on reaching the 10K limit (+2.277 more to go ... my goal is to reach that in the next 60 days ...). Then I'll be able to see with my own eyes what the complete story is. Apart from that: you're a moderator too. Therefor I think it's better I take the 5th ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I am not sure what you think you will find.  The post was brought to my attention.  It was closed for a month and was sitting at -1.  I saw no way to bring the question in line with the guidelines of this site.  The fact that there was a +19 answer had no bearing on the matter.  I left a message for posterity explaining why I deleted it.  And yes, I am a moderator.  Part of my duties are handling things like this.  We don't always get things right, and we don't always agree with each other.  If another mod feels strongly about my decision, then the will undelete the question.

Comment: You're from PA (USA), so you must know "the 5th", and I'm happy you don't know what "I" think. Just a few more very last things: (a) HOW was this post brought to your attention ? (b) You "left a message", but in such a way that "I" had to find out on my own what happened, not even some comment like "sorry, but as a moderator my job is to destroy this answer" (c) I really like the blog post you mentioned, especially the last phrase in it "Every question and answer ultimately should be about teaching and learning -- yes, even the shopping ones." ... What was Herci's question title? Over-and-out.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens The action wasn't against you or your answer.  It was against the question.  If I had deleted your answer instead of the question, you would be able to see my comment with the reason (this is common practice when mods delete answers).  The question was open-ended and extremely broad.  Those are not good fits on DA.  On SO, a question like that would have been gone in about 5 minutes.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Moderators don't publicly disclose how their attention was directed to a post, or which user did it, in the same way they don't publicly disclose other details.

Comment: OK, clear enough.

Comment: @MPD maybe to bad it wasn't gone in 5 minutes, it would save a lot of drama. That said, there are about 110 items waiting for final moderation decision...

Answer (score 1):

The only way you have to understand what happened is looking at your reputation page, which reports why you lost reputation; in this case, it says *removed* which could mean the answer was deleted, and in that case the link would take you to the answer, or the question was deleted, and in this case there would not be links until you aren't a 10K user. When you become a 10K user, the line showing the reputation change will contain a link to the deleted answer, and from there you can understand if it was the answer to be deleted, or the question.
As for why the post was deleted, you can see [Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions) and [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)

Wiki is not anymore used to salvage questions that are off-topic, which means off-topic questions would get closed even if they are marked as wiki.

Answer (score -2):

None of the previous answers so far contain a solution/answer for my "bullet 3." part of my question (which to me was the most important part of it). And the kind-of-work around to get an eMail copy of it, requires intervention (and goodwill) from some +10K rep user.

To avoid I'd have to bother any of the +10K rep users in the future, I started working on removing that dependency, by working on reaching that +10K rep myself. After I succeeded, I got access to all my "hidden for -10K user" answers, and even all deleted questions that these answers related to.

For anybody with a rep below +10K, feel free to [contact me via my profile at D.O](https://www.drupal.org/u/pierre.vriens) to help you recover any of your answers that are no longer available.